# StarterGui elements still appearing when set to invisible

Tags: lua, roblox

[image: this is where I have everything positioned in studio]I'm trying to use the PlayerAdded to make a screen gui disappear and make another one appear. It makes both guis appear though. I also am trying to make the player not spawn in when they join the game and that doesn't work either.

```
game.Player.CharacterAutoLoads = false

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    game.StarterGui.StartScreenFrame.Visible = true
    game.StarterGui.PlayGui.Visible = false
end)
```

Comment: As a small note, PlayFrame and StartScreenFrame look to be Frames that contain ScreenGuis. This is backwards. ScreenGuis should be the root that contain all other UI elements.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I got it all working now. I just took the quick route out by spawning everyone in a box, now everything works. I do have one more question though if you are available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation for StarterGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterGui).

> When a [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player)s’ character respawns, the contents of their [PlayerGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/PlayerGui) is emptied. Children of the StarterGui are then copied (along with their descendants) into the
> PlayerGui.

Stuff in the StarterGui acts as a template. The actual labels that show up on a player's screen are found in the player's PlayerGui. Your code is modifying the template, not the elements that are cloned to the PlayerGui.

Normally, to fix your problem, you would just need the correct paths to the UI elements. But you have a complicating factor, you've specified that `game.Players.CharacterAutoLoads = false`. This means that stuff in the StarterGui doesn't get cloned into the PlayerGui until the player's character spawns.

So I would recommend a few things :

- Move your UI Elements into ReplicatedStorage, this will prevent UI element duplication when you eventually tell your character to spawn into the world.
- Clone the elements into each player's UI manually. This will make the UI elements show up.
- Configure the cloned elements. This way you can script the UI behaviors yourself.

And then update your Script like this :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- get a reference to the UI templates
local startScreen = ReplicatedStorage.StartScreenFrame
local playScreen = ReplicatedStorage.PlayGui

-- disable character's auto loading
Players.CharacterAutoLoads = false

-- listen for when players first join the game
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- add the UI Elements to the PlayerGui
    local startGui = startScreen:Clone()
    startGui.Visible = true
    startGui.Parent = player.PlayerGui

    local playGui = playScreen:Clone()
    playGui.Visible = false -- enable this later
    playGui.Parent = player.PlayerGui
end)
```

Be aware that because you are manually placing UI Elements into the PlayerGui, you should be careful that when a Player dies and respawns, their PlayerGui will be cleared. You can avoid this by setting the [ResetOnSpawn](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/LayerCollector/ResetOnSpawn) property to false on each [ScreenGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ScreenGui).

Comment: Could you clarify where I should be putting this script?

Comment: [Scripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script) work anywhere in the Workspace or the ServerScriptService.

Comment: That's weird, it seems to delete the script from serverscriptservice when I join the game. Do you want me to send you a screen shot of where I have everything?

Comment: Do you have any other Scripts or plugins installed?

Comment: I have just what it gives you when you install it